# Ajax call in django admin panel

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, admin

My project contains a Loc model that saves lat,lng and address of a location. And to find location points more easily, I'm using google-map. The problem is, I want to update my google-map whenever address field is changed.

I don't know how to change admin views or is it possible to check requests in admin forms .. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this this snippet: [Google map on admin address field](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2154/)

It demonstrates the general idea and should be easily adjustable to your specific needs,

Answer (score 0):

You can override the template to include your Ajax javascript and call a custom view from that. Can't you?